# How to split integer to one digit?

Tags: python, integer

How would I split an 11 into to 1's to add together?

```
sums = int(input("Enter page sum: "))
page = 0
page2 = 0
tf = False

while(tf == False):
  page = page + 1
  page2 = page2 + page
  if (page2 == sums):
    break
print(page)
```

This is my current code. I need to change page2 to one digit if it goes over 9

Comment: What's your end goal? Please provide some number examples and the expected results.

Comment: If it counts up to 12 I'm trying to get this program to count 1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5 + 6 + 7 + 8 + 9 + 1 + 0 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 2

Comment: Convert the integer to a string, convert the string to a list of characters, then convert those characters to integers.

Comment: @Barmar This is not really a duplicate of the question you flagged. This one asks how to sum the digits of all the numbers up to some number. I agree it's similar, but it's not a duplicate.

Comment: @kwinkunks He already knows how to do the outer sum, he just needs to know how to sum the digits, which is what the other question answers.

Comment: @Barmar Right - fair point.

Answer (score 1):

You could turn it into a string, then break it up. For example:

```
number = 11

[int(c) for c in str(number)]
```

Or you could do it the mathematical way, with integer division and modulo:

```
number // 10, number % 10
```

Both of these give you a sequence of two 1's.

If I understand what you're trying to do properly, you could try this:

```
sum(n//10 + n%10 for n in range(1, sums + 1))
```

Which gives 51 when `sums` is 12. If you want to accept more digits, you'll have to add `n // 100` etc as well.

Answer (score 0):

```py
number = int(input("Please input a number: "))
sum = 0
counter = 0 # will count from 1-9, and reset if it goes too far

for n in range(number):
    if counter > 9:
        counter = 1 # limit the counter

    sum += counter
```

This will count up to the number you input, it will store the sum of the sequence from 1-9 that is managed by the counter.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this is what you are looking for,

```
sums = int(input("Enter page sum: ")) #Get the input
lst=map(str,list(range(1,sums+1))) #Map int list to string
lst_concat = ''.join(lst) #Merging the elements in the list together
lst2=list(lst_concat) #Make it into a list again
sum(map(int,lst2)) #Sum the elements of the digit
```